# Should API also authenticate users from front end app?

Tags: api-design, authentication, web-api, oauth2

I am building an API using Laravel and am looking at using Laravel/Passport for authentication - but I am struggling with a design decision.

The API will be consumed by multiple other applications / sites - initially an Angular web app that administers the data stored in the API, and another than will display certain data, but no updates or deletes etc.

How should I handle the two different types of authentication - ie firstly users who are allowed to log in to the Angular app, and secondly users who are allowed to query the API?

Should these be two different authentication methods/types? Should the Angular app just have a separate database to check users against?

Answer (score 2):

Well the users who are allowed to query the API can pass a secret key while others can login normally. You can add a condition which will confirm the case of API and validate the key.

But it is not good to use a single API for multiple purposes. If you want to authenticate users to login and pass queries to the API then it is better to use dual API.